# scaffold Many to Many Relation with nullable key

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I got a table with 3 one to many relations (one many to many relation and a third one to many relation with extra data), but I want to scaffold some relationships from one side of the many to many relation. I don't want it to be linked to the other side of the many to many relationship, so I was thinking of making that nullable but I (with no surprises) can't do that as it is a primary key for it. But is there a workaround to get a null for one side of the Many- to many relation?

Here is the SQL source:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConnectionPointRoutes] (
[ConnectionPointId] INT NOT NULL,
[RouteId]           INT NOT NULL,
[SegmentId]         INT NOT NULL,
[Position]          INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ConnectionPointRoutes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ConnectionPointId] ASC, [RouteId] ASC, [SegmentId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ConnectionPointRoutes_dbo.ConnectionPoints_ConnectionPointId] FOREIGN KEY ([ConnectionPointId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ConnectionPoints] ([ConnectionPointId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ConnectionPointRoutes_dbo.Routes_RouteId] FOREIGN KEY ([RouteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Routes] ([RouteId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ConnectionPointRoutes_dbo.Segments_SegmentId] FOREIGN KEY ([SegmentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Segments] ([SegmentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ConnectionPointId]
    ON [dbo].[ConnectionPointRoutes]([ConnectionPointId] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RouteId]
    ON [dbo].[ConnectionPointRoutes]([RouteId] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SegmentId]
    ON [dbo].[ConnectionPointRoutes]([SegmentId] ASC);
```

And this is the Model, notice that I made it nullable but the database still puts it down as a Not nullable item

```
namespace InBuildingNavigator.Data.Models
{
    public class ConnectionPointRoute
    {
        public int ConnectionPointId { get; set; }
        public int? RouteId { get; set; }
        public int? SegmentId { get; set; }
        public  int Position { get; set; }
        public ConnectionPoint ConnectionPoint { get; set; }
        public Route Route { get; set; }
        public Segment Segment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved here: [Optional One to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440035/optional-one-to-many-relationship)

the connectionpointroute modelbuilder had to be like this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ConnectionPointRoute>()
    .HasKey(c => new {c.ConnectionPointId, c.RouteId});
```